# Returning data from Room to ViewModel and later update the ViewModel with new data from webservice

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have a ViewModel and I am using LiveData, so I have a DAO that return LiveData> and I can get this to work, but really what I would want it to first show data from Room database if there are some, and then when the webservice has returned new data (if there are any) then write that to database and then update the ViewModel with the latest data from the database. I got as far as returning the data firstly from the database and also writing the new data to the database in the background, but then how do I get the ViewModel to read/update with the new data from the database again?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `DAO` return `LiveData<Any>`. It means that you can get notified about every change on that entity.

Assume that you have a `User` entity:

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var uid: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String
)
```

And its related DAO looks like:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun all(): LiveData<List<User>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(vararg users: User)
}
```

So, you just need to expose the result of `all` to your view layer:

```
class UserViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val users: LiveData<List<User>> = userDao.all()
}

class UserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<UserViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel.users.observe(this, Observer { users ->
            // show data
        })
    }
}
```

Now if you insert a new `User`, Your observer will be called.

This is the basic idea of how to get updated data from your DAO. But in your case what you actually must do is to create a `Repository` and inside that do your business logic, provide offline-first data and then try to get data from network and update database.

Comment: Thank you, I had this turned upside down in my head, but you got me back on track.